# mysql query to fetch group wise count

Tags: mysql, count

I am having mysql tables like below

tbl_source_1

```
SRC_ID_1 | SOURCE_NAME_1
1        | ABC
2        | DEF
3        | GHI
```

tbl_source_2

```
SRC_ID_2 | SOURCE_NAME_2
1        | NAME_1
2        | NAME_2
3        | NAME_3
```

tbl_user

```
user_id | user_nm
1       | JACK
2       | MACK
```

tbl_data

```
dta_id | SRC_ID_1 | SRC_ID_2 | user_id | data_name
1      | 1        | 1        | 1       | XYZ
2      | 1        | 1        | 1       | SAD
3      | 2        | 2        | 2       | BAD
```

now i want COUNT of data (group by source_2) and want result like below

```
SOURCE_NAME_1 | user_nm | NAME_1         | NAME_2 | NAME_3
ABC           | JACK    | 2 (it's count) |  0     | 0
DEF           | MACK    | 0              |  1     | 0
```

Comment: It's pivot. MySQL do not know about it. Emulate by `SUM(SOURCE_NAME_2='NAME_x')`.

Comment: what are NAME_1,NAME_2,NAME_3 fields i.e. how they are calculating..?

Comment: *i want COUNT of data (group by source_2) and want result like below* As I see you group data by `(source_1, user)` (?) and pivot (count) by separate `source_2` values.

Comment: @Chandan NAME_1 and NAME_2 is the values from tbl_source_2, and calculation - its a count of data that having NAME_1 or NAME_2 id in data table

Comment: @Akina Yes, group by source_1 and user and count by source_2

Answer (score 0):

> group by source_1 and user and count by source_2

Use pivot emulation:

```
SELECT SOURCE_NAME_1, 
       user_nm, 
       SUM(SOURCE_NAME_2 = 'NAME_1') NAME_1,
       SUM(SOURCE_NAME_2 = 'NAME_2') NAME_2,
       SUM(SOURCE_NAME_2 = 'NAME_3') NAME_3
FROM tbl_data 
LEFT JOIN tbl_user ON ...
LEFT JOIN tbl_source_1 ON ...
LEFT JOIN tbl_source_2 ON ...
GROUP BY SOURCE_NAME_1, user_nm
```

If SOURCE_NAME_2 values list is not static, use stored procedure which pivot data, or (better) count data only, then pivot it on the client side using client report subsystem.